# How to store byte[] in a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, file, byte

I want to store a byte[] in a text file using c#, where the file content should be between 0-255.

For instance the

```
byte [] =new byte[] {0,0, 255, 0, 0 ,0,189, 198, 200, 100,.....}
```

Content i want to see in the text file:

```
0,0, 255, 0, 0 ,0,189, 198, 200, 100,.....
```

I tried using various ways available for it:

1. this code writes unreadable symbols in the file.

   ```
   using (var fs = new FileStream(MyFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
   {
      fs.Write(by, 0, by.Length);               
   }
   ```
2. this code writes hex values like "00-00-FF-00-00-00-BD-C6-C8-64"

   ```
   File.WriteAllText(Myfilepath, BitConverter.ToString(Mybytearray));
   ```

Comment: How are you inspecting the file and what are these *"symbols"* you see?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see in the file. Do you want the byte value in readable ASCII form or binary? When you open the file in an editor and you see symbols, it probably is a binary file. The editor tries to interpret the values as ASCII or UTF-8 values an prints symbols.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Code shown in the post does indeed "store byte[] in a file in c#" (assuming `fs` is of type `byte[]`)... Please [edit] question to show input data and expected content of the file.

Comment: In the second one, you see hex values as text because that's what you told it to do by calling `BitConverter.ToString` and `File.WriteAllText`. "Works as implemented." You probably intended to call `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , I have added sample input and file output.

Comment: @madreflection i was juts trying various ways if i could get the same byte values in file eg--0,255,127,200......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one line of code to accomplish this:

```
File.WriteAllText(MyFilePath, string.Join(", ", bytes));
```